# Где находятся файлы шапки в gantry5?

Tags: php, html, joomla, gantry

Использую шаблон от gantry5, нужно отредактировать шапку (меню, логотипы) 
редактировать изменением кода, где можно найти файлы шапки? 
Мне нужно присвоить пунктам меню id для вывода подменю через jquery, где это можно редактировать?
В документации не нашел путей для правки кода, перерыл все

Еще нужно отредактировать файлы css, поменять их имена, но без доступа к коду я сделать этого не могу

Comment: обратите внимание на [документацию](http://docs.gantry.org/gantry5/advanced/customizing-theme-files)

Comment: @teran тут конкурс открыт. Не хотите ли написать ответ?